# How to add margin to bullet points?

Tags: css

I'd like to set some vertical margin between bullets points.  The following code has no effect.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">
ul li {martin-top:20px;}
</style>

testing
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kYDq8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`margin-top`, not `martin-top`

Also, in jsFiddle, you don't need the `<style></style>` tags in the style section - just the css.